# Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE although I'm not using any pendingIntent in application

Tags: android, firebase, rest, android-studio, android-pendingintent

I have already found similar answers for this but nothing work with my problem as I am getting this exception as-

> Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
> Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.

But this contains a condition as - **I am not using any PendingIntent in my application** . So its obvious that I cannot change the format of using it. I have these firebase dependencies-

```
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0' // add this
```

Can anyone please help!! what should I do for Android 12 simply API calling Using retrofit and observable and observers in presenter layer

Answer (score 9):

I got a similar error when receiving push messages even if I have not personally used `PendingIntent` in my application. It turns out that the error was coming from the `Firebase` library. I upgraded the `Firebase` library by replacing the following in `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.2.0'
```

with

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0"
```

Comment: In my case , the library which was creating issue was Chuck
`debugImplementation 'com.readystatesoftware.chuck:library:1.1.0` when I commented it, it works fine

Comment: I added above two lines of code, still have the Pending Intent issues, even I didn't use Pending Intent library, so how to resolve this issue?

Comment: How to see which library cause the issue, before target SDK was 30 it is ok, but SDK 31+ will cause this issue.

Comment: Finally this works, after trying to solve this issue since morning. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 7):

> But this contains a condition as - I am not using any PendingIntent in my application .

Something in your app is using a `PendingIntent`. It might be from a library. The full stack trace should give you more details.

> So its obvious that I cannot change the format of using it.

You would change the format by using an updated version of the library. For example, `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging` has a `23.0.6` patch version which might address the problem. If you cannot identify the specific library to update from the stack trace, make sure all of your libraries are up to date.

Comment: Thanks but in full stack trace I am unable to get anything related to that. From where do I get info? I updated firebase messaging dependency.